# Problem sending data to PHP on an AJAX-driven register form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm new to AJAX and I'm creating a register form which sends the data using AJAX.
I followed a tutorial which validates that the input fields are not empty and then sends the values to a PHP file and saves them to a database... and it works. But I'm also trying to integrate an extra script to check if the username is taken.

If I use -only- the script to check the availability of the username, without the tutorial one, it works like a charm. But the problem is when I try to combine both scripts.
Can someone help me out by pointing out my mistake(s)? I've tried many things and they make work only parts of the whole script, but not all of it.

Here's the tutorial working script model:

```
$(function() {
$('.error').hide();
$(".button").click(function() {
    // validate and process form
    // first hide any error messages
$('.error').hide();

  var name = $("input#name").val();
    if (name == "") {
  $("label#name_error").show();
  $("input#name").focus();
  return false;
}
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    if (email == "") {
  $("label#email_error").show();
  $("input#email").focus();
  return false;
}
    var phone = $("input#phone").val();
    if (phone == "") {
  $("label#phone_error").show();
  $("input#phone").focus();
  return false;
}

    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;
    //alert (dataString);return false;

    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "bin/process.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
      $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
    });
  }
 });
return false;
});
});
```

Here's my username check working code:

```
  $(function() {
$('.error').hide();

$(".button").click(function() {
$('.error').hide();
  // validate and process form here

var checkdata = username ['value'];
//alert ("usuario guardado =" + checkdata);

$.get("usernameCheck.php", { username: checkdata },
 function(data){
 //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);

    if ( data == 0 )
    {
    $("label#misuser_error").show();
    $("input#username").focus();
    return false;
    }


 });



return false; 


});
});
```

And here's my attempt to combine both:

```
$(function () {
$('.error').hide();
$(".button").click(function () {
$('.error').hide();
  // validate and process form here
    var flag = 1;
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $(" #password").val();
    var passwordC = $(" #password_confirm").val();
    var type = $(" #type").val();
    var name = $("#firstname").val();
    var lastname = $(" #lastname").val();
    var day = $(" #bdate_day").val();
    var month = $(" #bdate_month").val();
    var year = $(" #bdate_year").val();
    var email = $(" #email").val();
    var country = $(" #country").val();
    var state = $(" #state").val();
    var city = $(" #city").val();
    var payment_email = $(" #payment_email").val();


    if (username == "") {
    $("#username_error").show();
    $("#username").focus();
    return false;
    }
    else {

        if (password == "") {
        $(" #password_error").show();
        $(" #password").focus();
        return false;
        }
        else {

            if (passwordC == "") {
            $(" #password_confirm_error").show();
            $(" #password_confirm").focus();
            return false;
            }
            else {
                if ( password != passwordC ) {
                $(" #password_mismatch_error").show();
                $("#password_confirm").focus();
                return false;
                }
                else {

                    if (type == "") {
                    $(" #type_error").show();
                    $(" #type").focus();
                    return false;
                    }
                    else {

                        if (name == "") {
                        $("#firstname_error").show();
                        $("#firstname").focus();
                        return false;
                        }
                        else {

                            if (lastname == "") {
                            $(" #lastname_error").show();
                            $(" #lastname").focus();
                            return false;
                            }     
                            else {

                                if (day == "") {
                                $(" #bdate_day_error").show();
                                $(" #bdate_day").focus();
                                return false;
                                }    
                                else {

                                    if (month == "") {
                                    $(" #bdate_month_error").show();
                                    $(" #bdate_month").focus();
                                    return false;
                                    }    
                                    else {

                                        if (year == "") {
                                        $(" #bdate_year_error").show();
                                        $(" #bdate_year").focus();
                                        return false;
                                        }    
                                        else {

                                            if (email == "") {
                                            $(" #email_error").show();
                                            $(" #email").focus();
                                            return false;
                                            }    
                                            else {

                                                if (state == "") {
                                                $("#state_error").show();
                                                $(" #state").focus();
                                                return false;
                                                }
                                                else {

                                                    if (city == "") {
                                                    $("#city_error").show();
                                                    $(" #city").focus();
                                                    return false;
                                                    }    
                                                    else {

                                                        if (payment_email == "") {
                                                        $("#payment_email_error").show();
                                                        $(" #payment_email").focus();
                                                        return false;
                                                        }
                                                        else {
                                                                var flag = 1;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 


if (flag === 1) {

var checkdata = document.getElementById('username').value;
//alert ("usuario guardado =" + checkdata);

    $.get("usernameCheck.php", { username: checkdata },
        function(data){
            //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);

            if (data === 0) {
            $("label#misuser_error").show();
            $("input#username").focus();
            return false;
            }

    });


}



(function (save) {  
                //alert ("usuario guardado: " + checkdata);
                $.get("insert_user.php", { username: checkdata },
                function(sent){



                ('#userForm').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                  $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                  .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
                  .hide()
                  .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                    $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                  });


                  });
            return false;   
            }); 



});
});
```

Any thoughts, anyone?
I know i might be doing it all the wrong way, but I'm learning PHP/Javascript and AJAX only by taking tutorials. So have some mercy on me.

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I'll be honest - I did not read every line of your code. But I've done this kind of thing over and over, and I can tell you a few things that will prevent you from going wrong.

1. when creating your "datastring" try and use jquery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method. Also know that you can send your [data as an object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), not necessarily as a string. jquery will convert the object into "?a=b&c=d" for for you.
2. when validating, dont do this sort of "if else if". Do it the jquery way - use a plugin, or write your own. It will make your code much easier to read
3. use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). on ajax return, `console.log` your returned data to see what your PHP has to say about your request.
4. when doing a separate "username available" check, dont for get the same check in "insert user" - race conditions happen, plan for them.
5. check your syntax, and check if your methods are getting called. Firebug will help you there as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you're creating an unnecessary headache for yourself by structuring your validation code the way that you are. Remember, `return false` makes execution leave the function, so you don't need the deeply-nested if-else structure you've got.

Rather than this:

```
if(test) {
    // fail
} else {
   // second test
}
```

Use something like this

```
if(test) {
    // fail
}

if(test2) {
   // fail
}

// success
```

This is safe to do because the "fail" code, by returning false, will prevent execution from reaching the "success" code later on.

Here's a modified version of your script. NOTE: I removed a lot of your validation checks, and then added just two checks back so you could see the kind of pattern I'm recommending; you will want to add back in all the other necessary tests.

```
$(function () {
    $('.error').hide();
    $(".button").click(function () {

        $('.error').hide();

        // validate and process form here
        var flag = 1;
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $(" #password").val();
        var passwordC = $(" #password_confirm").val();
        var type = $(" #type").val();
        var name = $("#firstname").val();
        var lastname = $(" #lastname").val();
        var day = $(" #bdate_day").val();
        var month = $(" #bdate_month").val();
        var year = $(" #bdate_year").val();
        var email = $(" #email").val();
        var country = $(" #country").val();
        var state = $(" #state").val();
        var city = $(" #city").val();
        var payment_email = $(" #payment_email").val();

        if(!username.length) {
            $("username_error").show();
            $("username").focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(!password.length) {
            $("#password_error").show();
            $("#password").focus();
            return false;
        }

        // ... other checks
        var checkdata = $("username").val();

        $.get("usernameCheck.php", { username: checkdata }, function(data) {

            if(data === 0) {
                $("label#misuser_error").show();
                $("#username").focus();
                return false;
            }

            // DO SAVE HERE
            $.post("insert_user.php", { username: checkdata }, function(sent){
                ('#userForm').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                        $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                    });
                });
        });
    });
});
```

One more note: requests that change state on the server are supposed to be POSTs, not GETs. My sample code above indicates that.

Answer (score 0):

Uh. Not talking about your AJAX request, but best practices usually say that more than 3 nested 'if' is no good. Use something like this instead :

```
var fields = ['username', 'password', 'password_confirm', ... ];
var length = fields.length;
for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
  if ($('#' + fields[i]).val() == "") {
    $('#' + fields[i] + '_error').show();
    $('#' + fields[i]).focus();
  }
}
```

Also, your `$(".error").hide()` at your third line is useless.

Finally, I guess the not working part is your anonymous `(function (save)...`. This function is never executed. Add `();` at the end to have it executed.

Edit : the answer below shows a better way for your AJAX part.